# Prove that every Lebesgue measurable function is equal almost everywhere to a Borel measurable function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Suppose $(\mathbb{R},\Sigma(m),m)$ is our measure space, where $m$ is Lebesgue measure.  Also, suppose $f : \mathbb{R} \to [-\infty, \infty]$ is a Lebesgue measurable function.

The problem:

> Prove that $f$ is equal almost everywhere to a Borel measurable function.

**My attempt:**  We only have to prove this assertion for a non-negative Lebesgue measurable function $f$ because the result will follow for all Lebesgue measurable functions.

Furthermore, since any Lebesgue measurable function can be approximated by a sequence of non-negative, monotonically increasing, Lebesgue measurable simple functions $s_{n}$, we only need to prove the claim for an arbitrary Lebesgue measurable simple function.

So, let $s: \mathbb{R} \to [-\infty, \infty] $ be a Lebesgue measurable simple function.  We can write $s$ canonically as $$ s(x) = \sum \limits_{i = 1}^{n} \alpha_{i} \chi_{A_{i}}(x)$$ where $\alpha_{i} \in [-\infty, \infty]$, $\bigcup \limits_{i = 1}^{n} A_{i} = \mathbb{R}$, and $A_{i} \cap A_{j} = \emptyset$ if $i \neq j$.

For each $i$, since $A_{i}$ is Lebesgue measurable, we can find a Borel set $B_{i}$ such that $A_{i} \subseteq B_{i}$ and $m(B_{i} \setminus A_{i}) = 0$.  Clearly, this implies that $\bigcup \limits_{i = 1}^{n} B_{i} = \mathbb{R}$.  Now we just need the $B_{i}$'s to be pairwise disjoint, with each $B_{i}$ still retaining $A_{i}$.

To make them pairwise disjoint, I constructed the following sets:

$\tilde{B_{i}} = [B_{i} \setminus (\bigcup \limits_{j \neq i} B_{j})] \cup A_{i}$.  This construction gives us that the $\tilde{B_{i}}$'s are pairwise disjoint (I think....) and $A_{i} \subseteq \tilde{B_{i}}$.  But I don't know that $\tilde{B_{i}}$ is necessarily still a Borel set. :( :(  Am I approaching this problem all wrong?

Comment: Have you tried Lusin's theorem?

Comment: @UmbertoP. Lusin's theorem allows me to find a continuous function that is equal to my measurable function except on a set of measure less than $\epsilon$.  I will have to think about how to possibly apply that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just make sure you have countably many Lebesgue sets in your formulation, and from each of the disjoint sets remove sets of measure $0$ to make them Borel.

Almost everywhere equality follows, and that's all the question cares about.

Comment: And to be extra clear in case anyone stumbles across this page in the future, since for any Lebesgue measurable set $A$, we can find a Borel set $B$ such that $A \subseteq B$ and $m(B \setminus A) = 0$, the same holds true for $A^{c}$ since it is Lebesgue measurable.  But the Borel set $B'$ that we find for $A^{c}$ has the property that $(B')^{c}$ is a Borel set contained in $A$ with $m(A \setminus (B')^{c}) = 0$.  So for our simple function, we can reduce each Lebesgue measurable set $A_{i}$ to a Borel set $B_{i}$, and the resulting simple function is equal a.e. to $s$.

Comment: Also, the following argument is useful:  If $A$ is Lebesgue measurable, then so is $A^{c}$.  Find a Borel set $B$ such that $A^{c} \subseteq B$ and $m(B \setminus A^{c}) = 0$.  Then $B^{c}$ is a Borel set, and $B^{c} \subseteq A$.  But then $m(A \setminus B^{c}) = m(A \cap (B^{c})^{c}) = m(A \cap B) = m(B \setminus A^{c}) = 0$.  This shows that for any Lebesgue measurable set $E$, we can find a borel set $B$ with $B \subseteq E$ and $m(E \setminus B) = 0$.

Answer (score 4):

Hint.

Fact 1. If $f:\mathbb R\to [0,\infty]$ is Lebesgue measurable, then it expressed as
$$
f(x)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}a_n\chi_{A_n},
$$ 
where $A_n$ Lebesgue measurable and $a_n\in [0,\infty]$ - This can be shown approximating $f$ from below by simple functions, and then using Lebesgue's Monotone Convergence Theorem.

Fact 2. If $A$ is Lebesgue measurable, then there exists a Borel set $B$ such that
$$
m(A\smallsetminus B)+m(B\smallsetminus A)=0.
$$

Answer (score 4):

For any Lebesegue mesurable set $A_i$ exsists a Borel set $C_i$ such that $C_i \subseteq A_i$ and $m(A_i\setminus C_i)=0$. If $A_i$ are disjointed also $C_i$ are disjointed. Is not important that $$\bigcup^{n}_{i=1} {C_i} = \mathbb{R}$$ or, if you prefer, let $C=\bigcup^{n}_{i=1} {C_i}$ then
$$
t(x) = \sum^n_{i=i}{\alpha_i\chi_{C_i}(x)}+ 0\chi_{C^c}(x)
$$
in the required function ($C^c$ is trivially Borel-measurable).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: A lebesgue measurable set in $\mathbb{R}$ is a Borel measurable set, upto sets of measure $0$.

Comment: Did you read my attempt?

Comment: @user46944: yes. Show that the sets you defined are Borel sets up to null sets.

Comment: Well, they are Lebesgue measurable, but that means they are contained in Borel sets with the measure of the set difference being $0$.  But that gets me right back to where I started.  The new Borel sets are not necessarily pairwise disjoint, and if I try to make them pairwise disjoint, then my construction yields sets that are not necessarily Borel.  Then I can keep cycling like that forever. :(

Comment: @user46944 You just make sure you have countably many Lebesgue sets, and from each of the disjoint sets remove sets of measure 0 to make them Borel.

Comment: @AdamHughes I just realized that for each Lebesgue measurable set, we can also find a Borel measurable set that is contained inside of it, and which has the same measure as the measure of the original set.  So that means we can remove a set of measure $0$ from a Lebesgue measurable set to get a Borel measurable set.  So for our simple function $s$ in my answer, I can do that for each $A_{i}$, and that gives $n$ pairwise disjoint Borel sets.  But their union is no longer $\mathbb{R}$.  So is my new sequence of simple functions really converging to $f$?

Comment: @user46944 Almost everywhere, yes. That's all that matters, though.

Comment: @AdamHughes Ooh ok.  If you answer this question by copy-and-pasting what you've already written, I will accept your answer.  It was the most helpful to me.

Comment: @user46944 if you like. Just give me a minute.